# Does hsqldb provide functionality similar to an Oracle CURSOR?

Tags: java, oracle, hsqldb

In running my junit tests, I'm being given the error:

> user lacks privilege or object not found: CURSOR

The query is trying to load up a large number of records, with a subquery returning a corresponding one-to-many set of ids.

#### Code:

```
SELECT br.rateid, br.precedence, CURSOR (SELECT rt.trailerid FROM ratetrailer rt WHERE rt.rateid = br.rateid) AS trailer_ids FROM rate br WHERE br.statusID = ?
```

This works just fine as part of the java code, returning a ResultSet within the main ResultSet.

I have oracle compatibility turned on (`jdbc:hsqldb:mem:testDB;sql.syntax_ora=true`), but have a feeling this is an oracle shortcut/function/whatever rather than a simple syntax tweak. Is it?

Answer (score 0):

Returning a ResultSet in a column of another ResultSet is an Oracle feature that is not supported by HSQLDB and most other databases.